# ng2-charts: extra margin on axis

Tags: angular, charts, ng2-charts

I'm new to using ng2-charts in my application and I was wondering if I could increase the max value of the Y-axis by like 5 so that the top of my bar chart doesnt reach all the way to the top of the chart. Currently when I have a max value of 90, the max value of my Y-axis is also 90 and this causes some visually unpleasant overlap.

[image: Bar chart]

I'm currently using the default code from the documentation, which is as follows:

```js
public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: { xAxes: [{}], yAxes: [{}] }
  };

  public barChartLabels: Label[] = [
    '2006',
    '2007',
    '2008',
    '2009',
    '2010',
    '2011',
    '2012'
  ];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = this.fetchData();

  public changeChart(): void {
    this.barChartType = this.barChartType === 'bar' ? 'line' : 'bar';
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887677/chart-js-setting-max-y-axis-value-and-keeping-steps-correct Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `ngOnInit` method, you compute the maximum value found in any of your datasets.

```
const allValues = this.barChartData.flatMap(ds => ds.data);
const maxValue = Math.max(...allValues);
```

Then you define chart `options` and include `yAxes.tick.max`, giving it a value that is slightly bigger than `maxValue`.

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    max: Math.ceil(maxValue * 1.05)
  }
}]
```

The entire ngOnInit method would look as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const allValues = this.barChartData.flatMap(ds => ds.data);
  const maxValue = Math.max(...allValues);
  this.barChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          max: Math.ceil(maxValue * 1.05)
        }
      }]
      }
  };
}
```

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-dynamic-extra-margin-on-top?file=src/app/app.component.ts)